# Entries from one file not in second file

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm writing a library-management program. I've got a code, that asks if the entered username is in the user list and not in the list with locked persons (who haven't got the permissions to borrow books), but it doesn't work! Here's the code:

```
borrower=input("User ID: ")
        userlist = open("userlist.txt", "r")
        locked = open("locked.txt", "r")
        if borrower in userlist and borrower not in locked:
            #dosomething
        elif borrrower in userlist and borrower in locked:
            print("User",borrower,"isn't allowed to borrow books!")
        else:
            print("[ERROR] User",borrower,"doesn't exist!")
```

Please tell me what's wrong with this.

Answer (score 0):

You want the actual lists from those files.

```
userlist = open("userlist.txt", "r").readlines()
locked = open("locked.txt", "r").readlines()
```

Depending on how the data is actually structured, reading the file into a string would also be beneficial:

```
userlist = open("userlist.txt", "r").read()
locked = open("locked.txt", "r").read()
```

The difference between these two:  `readlines()` gives you back a list, and `read()` gives you back a string.  The difference in behavior of `in` between these two:  if it's a list, if it's embedded in a string, it won't pick it up; if it's in a string, it'll pick it up.